# Emit event to single client in backbone.io

Tags: backbone.js, socket.io

I'm using backbone.io from https://github.com/scttnlsn/backbone.io, and would like to emit an event to a single client using that client's socket id. So rather than doing `backend.emit('created', { id: 'myid', foo: 'bar' });` which will emit the event to all clients, I'd like to emit to a single client.

What's the best way of doing this?

Comment: Just create a channel to which your client is the only subscriber.

Comment: I should add that the data should only be available to a single user account with the correct session data. Are channels a suitable way of separating user specific data (e.g setting the channel to the user id)?  Isn't it possible to subscribe to arbitrary channels?

Comment: Or would it be better to set the channel to the user's session id? Then it is not easy to access another user's channel.

Answer (score 1):

I would do this:

Set up a channel for each user.  If you need to make it hard for other clients to listen, name the channel with a hash based on the user id and the login time or something.  Tell the client to listen to that channel.

Then if you want to send something to a specific user, you can look at your database, see their id and their login time, and then send data to that specific user.

Comment: OK, this would work. I'd still like to know though if there is something analogous to `io.sockets.socket('thesocketid').emit` in backbone.io.